# How can I use Kinect 360 with Windows?

Tags: windows, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to connect Kinect 360 with Windows.

What I try:
I try to connect it with Windows 10 (64-bit) and Windows 8.1 (64-bit) (both ware host OS).

1. I downloaded and Installed the Software Development Kit (SDK).
2. I downloaded and installed the Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8.
3. I downloaded and installed the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit v1.8.
4. Then, I plug the Kinect 360 in the electric power and connect it with my Lap Top using the USB 3. I am using a power supply adapter cable for Xbox 360 Kinect Sensor (see the picture below).
   [image]

As a result, no new hardware ware listed in the Device Manager like no new microphone, no new camera, no new unknown devices.

BTW I am not sure if the Kinect hardware is working at all. I don't know how to check it - there aren't any lighting lights on it. I did some research, but I didn't see any lights on working Kinect 360 on youtube videos. So I don't know how to test whether the Kinect is working (without connecting it with XBOX).

I want to connect the Kinect sensor with the PC machine because I need to do some tests. If there are other solutions with another OS (like Linux-based or MAC OS), I can try it too.

Answer (score 1):

there was the same problem, it shows up as a microphone, I thought the problem was in the kinect itself (I thought it was broken) so it lay on the shelf for 2 years. I updated my PC 4 months ago and it turned out that there is usb 3.0 on my old motherboard, but it is not supported (perhaps 3.2 is needed for it). Now kinect works fine and is being determined